# Иконки дисков и флешек в Windows 11

Tags: windows, windows-11

Как сделать, чтобы у жёстких дисков и флешек были разные иконки?

[image: скриншот]

Answer (score 1):

Самый простой метод будет назначить стационарным дискам иконку через `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\DriveIcons`. Нужно создать раздел с буквой диска и в нем раздел DefaultIcon

Поставь значение `%SystemRoot%\System32\shell32.dll,8` (стандартная) или свою иконку для каждого диска.

Иконка для дисков назначается в разделе `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Drive\DefaultIcon`, но не вижу отдельного раздела для флешек.

Поставь `%SystemRoot%\System32\shell32.dll,7` (съемный диск)

Comment: Для каждого диска отдельно? Я по типам хотел, чтобы автоматически ставилось.

Comment: по типам не нашел разделения... только для всех и по буквам

Comment: но ведь в win10 были разные иконки... Кстати, а зачем ты пробелов в ветке реестра наставил?

Comment: копипаста не с того места)

Comment: @Qwertiy в win10 иконки тоже одинаковые https://i.stack.imgur.com/7zn8S.png

Comment: @andreymal, ой...

Comment: @Qwertiy сейчас размечал разделы на системном SSD на Windows 11, и после создания нового раздела винда спросила, что делать со съёмным носителем. Видимо, различать диски и флешки это непосильная задача для винды ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: @andreymal после того как хотплаг добавили на sata порты наверное на эти иконки и положили... в XP вроде иконки были разные.